# Incorrect Scope Syntax with SQL Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to limit a query to only return results that belong to a logged in user and within a date range. This is the scope:

```
scope :unpaid, ->(start_date, end_date, current_user) { joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN carrier_commissions ON
  dealer_commissions.phone_id = carrier_commissions.phone_id AND
  dealer_commissions.name = carrier_commissions.name')
  .where('carrier_commissions.id IS NULL').where('customer_id: current_user.customer.id, created_at: start_date..end_date') }

  def self.reconciliation(start_date, end_date, current_user)

    ...

    dealer_commissions.unpaid.each do |unpaid|
      unpaid.update(status: "Unpaid", discrepancy_balance: unpaid.payment)
      if unpaid.initial_discrepancy.blank?
        unpaid.update(initial_discrepancy: unpaid.payment)
      end
    end

  end
```

And here is `reconcile` controller action that has the actual parameters:

```
  def reconcile
    start_date = Date.new(params[:range][:"start_date(1i)"].to_i,params[:range][:"start_date(2i)"].to_i,params[:range][:"start_date(3i)"].to_i)
    end_date = Date.new(params[:range][:"end_date(1i)"].to_i,params[:range][:"end_date(2i)"].to_i,params[:range][:"end_date(3i)"].to_i)
    DealerCommission.reconciliation(start_date, end_date, current_user)
    redirect_to dealer_commissions_url, notice: 'Dealer commissions reconciled.'
  end
```

This is a sample from my logs:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "dealer_commissions" LEFT OUTER JOIN carrier_commissions ON
    dealer_commissions.phone_id = carrier_commissions.phone_id AND
    dealer_commissions.name = carrier_commissions.name WHERE "dealer_commissions"."customer_id" = ? AND ("dealer_commissions"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-02-03' AND '2015-06-03') AND (carrier_commissions.id IS NULL) AND (customer_id: current_user.customer.id, created_at: start_date..end_date)  [["customer_id", 8]]
SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: ":": SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "dealer_commissions" LEFT OUTER JOIN carrier_commissions ON
    dealer_commissions.phone_id = carrier_commissions.phone_id AND
    dealer_commissions.name = carrier_commissions.name WHERE "dealer_commissions"."customer_id" = ? AND ("dealer_commissions"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-02-03' AND '2015-06-03') AND (carrier_commissions.id IS NULL) AND (customer_id: current_user.customer.id, created_at: start_date..end_date)
```

The goal is to get the records with those condition (`start date, end date, current_user`).

Comment: `(customer_id: current_user.customer.id, created_at: start_date..end_date)` doesn't look like valid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your syntax. At the moment you're passing a static string to mysql, not including your rails variables.

```
.where('customer_id = ? AND created_at > ? AND created_at < ?', current_user.customer.id, start_date, end_date)
```

Comment: Error: undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<Class:0x00000003ea31b8>

Comment: You should pass the variables to unpaid scope: `dealer_commissions.unpaid(current_user, date_from, date_to)`

Comment: I can't go about and correct all of your code on Stackoverflow. Especially if it's missing pieces. You need to pass the variables from somewhere where you have them...

Comment: `current_user` is only passed as a param from the controller in the `reconcile` action.